# Connecting to Spotify API using R- Authentication Token Issue

Tags: r, httr, spotify-app

I am trying to connect to spotify API to get some data from my recently listened to tracks using this link "https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-recently-played/?limit=&after=&before=". In order to access this API, however, I need to generate an authentication code. I am unsure about how to incorporate this authentication token into my "GET" statement (or R code in general) in order to connect to the API. I am currently using the "HTTR" package in r to do this, not sure what I'm doing wrong. See my sample code below:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite) #for parsing the response could also use library(xml2)
library(dplyr)

user_id="xxxxxx"
Token="BQAPSJ4ckLLUCXZCyMl2_c0eiOrC0xV3oJLXP1eIABz8RJALGRMQ7-kIenzq_868Pt3bJPsIdGV753_QOv6F79-8XQVBnaEPXT93pDVXeId98m8RcH2_z37saM1QnMrmxmytTAr-bofPrZQ"

response = POST(
 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/recently-played',
  accept_json(),
  authenticate(user_id, Token), Authorization="bearer"
)

mytoken = content(response)$access_token
HeaderValue = paste0('Bearer ', mytoken)
```

The error I'm currently getting is
[https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/recently-played]](https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/recently-played%5D)
Date: 2021-06-30 00:38
Status: 400
Content-Type: application/json
Size: 99 B
{
"error": {
"status": 400,
"message": "Only valid bearer authentication supported"
}

> 

Thank you so much in advance for any help.

Comment: maybe try `GET("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/recently-played", add_headers(Authorization=paste("Bearer", Token))`